# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined node js

Tags: node.js

Code:

```
console.log("NOW()")
console.log(new Date())
connection.query(fetchActiveRequests, values, function(err, result_requests) {
  console.log("==================== getActiveRequestsIfAny") 
  console.log(result_requests)
  var result_requests_length = result_requests.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < result_requests_length; i++) { 
    result_requests[i].current_time = result_requests[i].request_made_on
      .toISOString()
      .replace(/T/, ' ')
      .replace(/\..+/, '');
    result_requests[i].time_left = 60;
  }
```

Error:

```
undefined
/var/www/html/taxinew/ilmp-server/app-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Query._callback (/var/www/html/taxinew/ilmp-server/app-server/routes/ride_parallel_dispatcher.js:3555:58)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/var/www/html/taxinew/ilmp-server/app-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/www/html/taxinew/ilmp-server/app-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:90:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/html/taxinew/ilmp-server/app-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/html/taxinew/ilmp-server/app-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/html/taxinew/ilmp-server/app-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/taxinew/ilmp-server/app-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: console.log("NOW()")
        console.log(new Date())
        connection.query(fetchActiveRequests, values, function(err, result_requests) {

            console.log("==================== getActiveRequestsIfAny")
            console.log(result_requests)

            var result_requests_length = result_requests.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < result_requests_length; i++) {
                result_requests[i].current_time = result_requests[i].request_made_on.toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '');
                result_requests[i].time_left = 60;
            }

Comment: @AmitKumarSingh You can edit info into the original question. Can you explain a little bit about what you are trying to achieve? The query is returning an undefined value which you can't use as an array.

Comment: Why not add check condition for undefined or null `result_requests?result_requests.length:0`

Answer (score 0):

> `result_requests` is `undefined`. Probably you are getting an error, and
>   you are not handling the error in your code.